# Django how to get specific field with complex join in one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, get, one-to-many

I have a database consists of 3 tables

- Project table
- Section table
- Task table

And the their relationships

- Project table have one-to-many relation ship with Section table.
- Section table have one-to-many relation ship with task table.

I have already queried a target task record by this code

```
 task = tasks.objects.filter(section_id=sectionID)
```

Assume that I have sectionID and then I would like to get project.id from a task object, what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to reach it using `task.section.project.id`. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you models look like that:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    #...


class Section(models.Model):
    #...
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)


class Task(models.Model):
    #...
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
```

So in order to get a task `project` you just have to follow the relation.

```
#when task is a single task object
project = task.section.project
```

Have in mind that this will make 2 queries *(one to get the `section` and one to get the `project`)* you can optimize this with `select_related`

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(section_id=sectionID).select_related('section__project')
for task in tasks:
    project = task.section.project
    print project.id
```

ending with a single query.

I guess you can also want to know how to get a `queryset` of `projects` contained by some `sectionID`, in this case you can use the reverse relations like so:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(section__id=sectionID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach it using `task.section.project.id`.